# Abstraction to make URLs (many different schemes) act like Paths on disk

Tags: python, library, url

The config file for my project takes many files and directories. It would be convenient if these files and directories could reference git repositories, zip archives, possibly over https. This function converts those URLs to paths on the disk, so the rest of the project still only deals with `Path`s on disk.

Did I handle the sub-schemes according to the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)? I haven't seen many other programs that do this (except for [Pip with VCS URLs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support)).

Is there any unnecessary repetition that you see?

```py
async def pathify(
    url_str: str,
    base: Path,
    cache_path: Path,
    should_exist: bool,
    should_dir: bool,
    session: Optional[aiohttp.ClientSession] = None,
) -> Path:
    """Takes a URL, copies it to disk (if not already there), and returns a local path to it.

Args:
    url_str (str): the URL in question
    base (Path): the base path for resolving relative file paths
    cache_path (Path): the location where this fn will put objects
    should_exist (bool): ensure that the file exists or raise ValueError (applicable to the file: scheme)
    should_dir (bool): expect the url to point to a directory, otherwise a file, and raise ValueError if that expectation is violated
    session (Optional[aiohttp.ClientSession]): aiohttp session to be used if URLs are http/https

Returns:
    Path: a path to the resource on the local disk. Do not modify the file at this path.

Supported schemes:

 - `http:` and `https:`
 - Does not support sub-schemes.
 - Caller must pass a aiohttp session.
 - Result is cached
 - Returns files (not directories)

 - `zip:`
 - Requires a sub-scheme (e.g. `zip+file:///path/to/archive.zip`)
 - Calls `unzip` on the file returned by the sub-scheme
 - Result is cached
 - Returns directories

 - `git:`
 - Supports optional sub-schemes
 - Calls `git clone` on the URL with the sub-scheme
    - Optionally, A branch, tag, or commit hash can be appended to the URL after a `@`.
    - e.g. `git+https://github.com/a/b@v1` calls `git clone -b v1 https://github.com/a/b`
 - Result is cached
 - Inspired by [Pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support)
 - Returns directories

 - `file:` (default if no scheme is provided)
 - Supports optional sub-schemes
 - Supports absolute (e.g. file://path/to/file) and relative (file:path/to/file), where relative paths are resolved relative to `base`
 - Also accepts the path through a `path` fragment argument
    - This way, one can specify a path within a directory retrieved by another scheme (e.g. file+git://github.com/a/b#path=path/within/repo).
 - Returns files or directories

    """


    url = urllib.parse.urlparse(url_str)
    cache_dest = Path(cache_path / escape_fname(url_str))
    first_scheme, _, rest_schemes = url.scheme.partition("+")
    fragment = urllib.parse.parse_qs(url.fragment)

    if first_scheme in set(["http", "https"]) and not rest_schemes:
        if should_dir:
            raise ValueError(
                f"{url} points to a file (because of the http[s] scheme) not a dir"
            )
        elif cache_dest.exists():
            return cache_dest
        elif session is None:
            raise ValueError(f"{url_str} given, so aiohttp.ClientSession expected")
        else:
            async with session.get(url_str) as src:
                async with AIOFile.open(cache_dest, "wb") as dst:
                    await dst.write(await src.read())
            return cache_dest
    elif first_scheme == "file" and rest_schemes and "path" in fragment:
        underlying_fragment = {key: val for key, val in fragment.items() if key != "path"}
        underlying_fragment_str = urllib.parse.urlencode(underlying_fragment, doseq=True)
        dir_url = urllib.parse.urlunparse(
            (rest_schemes, *url[1:5], underlying_fragment_str)
        )
        dir_path = await pathify(dir_url, base, cache_path, True, True, session)
        path_within_dir = Path(fragment["path"][0])
        path = dir_path / path_within_dir
        if should_exist and not path.exists():
            raise ValueError(f"Expected {path_within_dir} to exist within {dir_url}")
        elif path.exists() and (path.is_dir() != should_dir):
            raise ValueError(
                f"{path_within_dir} points to a {'dir' if path.is_dir() else 'file'} "
                f"but a {'dir' if should_dir else 'file'} expected"
            )
        else:
            return path
    elif first_scheme == "zip" and rest_schemes:
        if not should_dir:
            raise ValueError(
                f"{url} points to a dir (because of the zip scheme) not a file"
            )
        elif cache_dest.exists():
            return cache_dest
        else:
            archive_url = urllib.parse.urlunparse((rest_schemes, *url[1:]))
            archive_path = await pathify(
                archive_url, base, cache_path, True, False, session
            )
            await subprocess_run_async(["zip", str(archive_path), "-d", str(cache_dest)])
            return cache_dest
    elif first_scheme == "git":
        if not should_dir:
            raise ValueError(
                f"{url} points to a dir (because of the git scheme) not a file"
            )
        elif cache_dest.exists():
            return cache_dest
        else:
            repo_scheme = url.scheme.partition("+")[2]  # could be git+b+c, we want b+c
            repo_url, _, rev = urllib.parse.urlunparse((repo_scheme, *url[1:6])).partition("@")
            rev_flags = ["-b", rev] if rev else []
            await subprocess_run_async(["git", "clone", *rev_flags, repo_url, str(cache_dest)])
            return cache_dest
    elif first_scheme in set(["file", ""]) and not rest_schemes:
        # no scheme; just a plain path
        path = Path(url.path)
        normed_path = path if path.is_absolute() else Path(base / path)
        if should_exist and not normed_path.exists():
            raise ValueError(f"Expected {normed_path} to exist")
        elif normed_path.exists() and (normed_path.is_dir() != should_dir):
            raise ValueError(
                f"{normed_path} points to a {'dir' if normed_path.is_dir() else 'file'} "
                f"but a {'dir' if should_dir else 'file'} expected"
            )
        else:
            return normed_path
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unsupported urlscheme {url.scheme}")
```